# Usar un prepared statement para eliminar un registro por id en Java

Tags: java, mysql, sql, prepared-statements

necesito saber como hacer un *delete* buscando el `id`

Esto es lo que tengo:

```
package Principal;

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Galerias {
    Connection con = null;

    public void Insertar(String nombre, String ubicacion, String comuna, String pais, String desc) {
        Conexion conexion = new Conexion();
        con = conexion.AbrirConexion();
        PreparedStatement ps = null;

        try {
            String consulta = "INSERT INTO galerias (nombreGaleria, ubicacionGaleria, comunaGaleria, paisGaleria, idGaleria) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)";

            ps = con.prepareStatement(consulta);
            ps.setString(1, nombre);
            ps.setString(2, ubicacion);
            ps.setString(3, comuna);
            ps.setString(4, pais);
            ps.setString(5, desc);

            ps.executeUpdate();
            con.close();
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            System.out.println(ex.toString());
        }
    }

    public ArrayList SelectAll() {
        Conexion conexion = new Conexion();
        con = conexion.AbrirConexion();
        PreparedStatement ps = null;
        ResultSet rs = null;
        ArrayList<String> lista = new ArrayList<>();

        try {
            String consulta = "SELECT * FROM galerias";

            ps = con.prepareStatement(consulta);
            rs = ps.executeQuery();

            while (rs.next()) {
                lista.add(rs.getInt(1) + ";" + rs.getString(2) + ";" + rs.getString(3) + ";" + rs.getString(4) + ";" + rs.getString(5));
            }

            con.close();
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            System.out.println(ex.toString());
        }

        return lista;
    }
}
```

Comment: necesito saber como hacer un delete buscando el id

Comment: Abajo te dejé un ejemplo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Recuerda formular bien tu pregunta, para eliminar sería así.

```
public void eliminar(String idGaleria) { //En caso de INT (Int idGaleria)
    Conexion conexion = new Conexion();
    con = conexion.AbrirConexion();
    PreparedStatement ps = null;

    try {
        String consulta = "DELETE FROM galerias WHERE idGaleria = ? ";
        ps.setString(1, idGaleria);  // ps.setInt(1, idGaleria); <--- En caso de ser INT
        ps = con.prepareStatement(consulta);
        ps.executeQuery();
        con.close();
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        System.out.println(ex.toString());
    }
}

     public void Update(String nombreGaleria, String ubicacionGaleria, 
            String comunaGaleria, String paisGaleria, String idGaleria) { 
    Conexion conexion = new Conexion();
    con = conexion.AbrirConexion();
    PreparedStatement ps = null;

    try {
        String consulta = "UPDATE galerias SET nombreGaleria = ? , ubicacionGaleria = ?, "
                + "comunaGaleria = ?, paisGaleria = ? WHERE idGaleria = ? ";
        ps.setString(1, nombreGaleria); 
        ps.setString(2, ubicacionGaleria); 
        ps.setString(3, comunaGaleria); 
        ps.setString(4, paisGaleria); 
        ps.setString(5, idGaleria);  
        ps = con.prepareStatement(consulta);
        ps.executeQuery();
        con.close();
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        System.out.println(ex.toString());
    }
}
```

Comment: y para un update ?? por favor

Comment: Añadido. Espero te sirva.